# Data not showing in <lightning:datatable/>

Tags: apex, javascript, lightning-datatable

I have problem displaying data in datatable.

[image: Empty datatable]

I've tested the code with some alerts just to see if I was correctly mapping fieldName:value for the table and it is correct, but for some reason it isn't showing.

Columns for datatable are dynamic - based on multiselect picklist, and the data should be mapped appropriately for each column. The data I get from my Apex API call is List and it looks like this -->

[image: Data]

I've made some alerts just to see if I was getting individual rows in the data and it looks like this -->
[image: Individual Row]

Lastly, I've made an alert to see if the fieldName and the value are mapping correctly, looks like this -->

[image: FieldName]
[image: FieldName1]

etc.... Based on how many columns the user has selected

The for loop for filling the datatable is this (the first for loop is 0-100 because the server always returns 100 rows, second loop is based on all selected columns from user):

```
if(state === "SUCCESS") {
                    var responseData = response.getReturnValue();
                    //var jsonString = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(responseData));
                    alert(responseData);
                    // used for getting the size of an List of all columns for the loop
                    var columnsList = component.get("v.columns");
                    var data=[];
                    // data for dataTable
                    for(var i=0;i<100;i++){
                        var row = responseData[i];
                        alert(row);
                        for(var j=0;j<columnsList.length;j++){
                            var column = columnsList[j].fieldName;
                            alert(column + " " + row[j]);
                            data.push({column:"row[j]"});
                        } 
                    }
                    component.set("v.dataTableData", data);
                }
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

**EDIT 1 --> console.log:**

[image: json response]
[image: console.log(elements)]

**EDIT 2 --> console.log(columnList);**

[image]

[image]

**EDIT 3 --> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')**

[image: typeError]

I've noticed that API returns the same column 4 times (session_id,visitor_id,timestamp,session_unique_content_impressions x4)..

**NOTE**: This is Dummy data, there's no privacy concerns.

Comment: I would better show the data to Browser Console using  **console.log(responseData);** to see what data you are getting.

Comment: Thank you. I've updated my question with console.log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are pushing each **row element** as different row. It is your mistake.

This JS code should work for you

```js
if(state === "SUCCESS") {
    try {
        let responseData = JSON.parse( response.getReturnValue() );
        //var jsonString = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(responseData));
        console.log(responseData)
        // used for getting the size of an List of all columns for the loop
        var columnsList = component.get("v.columns");
        var data=[];
        // data for dataTable
        responseData.data.forEach( row => {
            console.log(row)
            let newRow = {};
            row.forEach( (element, index) => {
               newRow[columnsList[index].fieldName] = element;
            });
            data.push(newRow);
        })
        component.set("v.dataTableData", data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }

}
```

This code will work if you get `columnsList` dynamically,
And the length and order in  `columnsList` will **always be the same** as in the **data** rows which you retrieve in your **Apex** method.

Comment: The data isn't showing even tho I have columnList dynamically. I've updated the question with console log. Also, I tried console.log(newRow); but it doesn't show. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Stojcheski Check if you need to call **responseData.data.forEach** or just **responseData.forEach**. Also I updated the answer in some way. Try the latest code from the answer.

Comment: I've updated my question - Edit 3, I tried responseData.forEach - got forEach is not a function - then I tried the updated code and I got TypeError.

Comment: @Stojcheski Ok, You need to parse your data into Object, as from Apex you get String. I added **let responseData = JSON.parse( response.getReturnValue() );** to the answer.

Comment: That worked. You saved me tons of time. You rock.

Comment: @Stojcheski you are welcome :)